# How to add double quotes to a line with SED or AWK?

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, text-processing

I have the following list of words:

```
name,id,3
```

I need to have it double quoted like this:

```
"name,id,3"
```

I have tried `sed 's/.*/\"&\"/g'` and got:

```
"name,id,3
```

Which has only one double quote and is missing the closing double quote.

I've also tried `awk {print "\""$1"\""}` with exactly the same result. I need help.

Comment: Your sed command works on my computer. You can omit the backslash before the double quotes since they are useless in a single quoted string.

Comment: hmmm, yes, this is weird. I get one double quote all the same. My original file is file.csv -- has a long list of "name,id,[[:num:]]". Why doesn't it work?

Comment: The `g` isn't necessary, but it's not causing your problem. What is your platform?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your input file has carriage returns at the end of the lines. You need to use `dos2unix` on the file to remove them. Or you can do this:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\r/"\1"/g'
```

which will remove the carriage return and add the quotes.

Comment: that worked! you're right, the file comes from windows and was generated in windows

Comment: great solution! can you put some light on what \r and "\1" is doing here ?

Comment: @satch_boogie: `\r` is a carriage return. `\1` is the contents of the capture done by the parentheses (so in this case, the entire line before the carriage return). The result is that the carriage return is removed and quotes are added. I think the `g` (global) at the end is unnecessary, but my answer preserved it from the OP's question. See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for more information about capturing groups.

Answer (score 29):

Use this to pipe your input into:

```
sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/'
```

`^` is the anchor for line start and `$` the anchor for line end. With the `sed` line we're replacing the line start and the line end with `"` and `"` respectively.

Example:

```
$ echo -e "name,id,2\nname,id,3\nname,id,4"|sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/'
"name,id,2"
"name,id,3"
"name,id,4"
```

without the `sed`:

```
$ echo -e "name,id,2\nname,id,3\nname,id,4"
name,id,2
name,id,3
name,id,4
```

**Your file seems to have DOS line endings. Pipe it through `dos2unix` *first*.**

Proof:

```
$ cat test.txt
name,id,2
name,id,3
name,id,4
$ sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' test.txt
"name,id,2
"name,id,3
"name,id,4
$ cat test.txt|dos2unix|sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/'
"name,id,2"
"name,id,3"
"name,id,4"
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use awk instead of sed like this:

```
line='name,id,3'
echo $line | awk '{printf("\"%s\"\n", $0);}'
```

OR even better is to use BASH printf like this:

```
printf '"%s"\n' $line
```

Comment: I have command as this, but i need each output line to be enclosed within " ". How to modify this command? :awk '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) { printf("%s ", $i);  } printf("\n") }' all.txt  > result.txt

Comment: To quote each line just use: `awk '{printf("\"%s\"\n", $0)}' file`

Answer (score 7):

Simplest way I've found is to use the HEX codes for double quotes:

```
 echo name,id,3 | awk '{print "\x22" $1 "\x22"}'
 "name,id,3"
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @Dennis solution,

Use

```
sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/g'
```

No need to look for '\r', This will apply double quote for all strings. 
This does not require run dos2unix on the input file.

Answer (score -1):

Before using sed command, you can use \ as escape character then it will print " in your string. As an example, i put the similar string to first line of a text file with below command:

```
var = "\"name,id,3\""
sed -i '1i' "$var" /tmp/out.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
echo name,id,3 | sed 's/name,id,3/"name,id,3"/'
"name,id,3"
```