# How can I add quotation marks to fields in a CSV file?

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I've got a CSV file like

```
Brand,Type,Color
Porsche,Sport,Red
BMW,Coupe,Blue
```

I'd like to include quotation marks to have it like:

```
"Brand","Type","Color"
"Porsche","Sport","Red"
"BMW","Coupe","Blue"
```

What's the fastest way to do it? I will implement it in a cronjob.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754682/how-to-add-double-quotes-to-a-line-with-sed-or-awk ... :)

Comment: Thanks summea, seems I suck at googling!!

Comment: No problem!  I hope it provides an answer for you that works :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed -e 's/^\|$/"/g' -e 's/,/","/g' input
```

Comment: Note that this will mishandle any commas that appear within double quotes in the input file. It will also mishandle any values that are already double-quoted. In other words, it only works correctly if every value in the input file is unquoted.

Answer (score 4):

It's often neater to use a language with a CSV library for CSV data:

```
ruby -rcsv -ne 'puts CSV.generate_line(CSV.parse_line($_), :force_quotes=>true)'
```

Comment: This is actually neat! It takes care of those cases 9as I had) where some fields were quoted and some were not.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[^,]+/"&"/g' file
```

---

Accounting for the presence of `"`'s and escaped characters.

```
sed -E 's/[^\,"]*(("|[\].)[^"\,]*)*/"&"/g' file
```

Comment: Note that this will mishandle any commas that appear within double quotes in the input file. It will also mishandle any values that are already double-quoted. In other words, it only works correctly if every value in the input file is unquoted.

Comment: @JohnKarahalis if double quotes were to appear in the field I guess they would need to be escaped (otherwise it would be hard to reverse the required change). However a solution which takes this in mind might look like the above.

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/[^,]+/,"\"&\"")}1' file.csv
```

Comment: Note that this will mishandle any commas that appear within double quotes in the input file. It will also mishandle any values that are already double-quoted. In other words, it only works correctly if every value in the input file is unquoted.