# Linux/Unix bash basic script awk/sed

Tags: linux, csv, sed, awk

I'm working on bash script.

```
var=$(ls -t1 | head -n1);
cat $var | sed 's/"//g' > latest.csv
cat latest.csv | sed -e 's/^\|$/"/g' -e 's/,/","/g' > from_epos.csv
echo "LATEST: $var";
```

Here's the whole script, it's meant to delete all quotation mark from current file and add new one, between each field.

INPUT:

```
"sku","item","price","qty"
5135,"ITEM1",1.79,5
5338,"ITEM2",1.39,5
5318,"ITEM3",1.09,5
5235,"ITEM4",1.09,5
9706,"ITEM5",1.99,5
```

OUTPUT:

```
"sku","item","price","qty"
"5135","ITEM1","1.79","5
"
"5338","ITEM2","1.39","5
"
"5318","ITEM3","1.09","5
"
"5235","ITEM4","1.09","5
"
"9706","ITEM5","1.09","5
"
```

My ideal output is:

```
"sku","item","price","qty"
"5135","ITEM1","1.79","5"
"5338","ITEM2","1.39","5"
"5318","ITEM3","1.09","5"
"5235","ITEM4","1.09","5"
"9706","ITEM5","1.99","5"
```

It seems like it's entering random  character between line in current output like
 "  and quotation mark is between CR and LF.

What's the problem and how to get it to my ideal vision?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: You approach seems wrong. If you need to treat a CSV, use a real programming language and a proper parser

Comment: I've tried running your script against the provided input, it did provide the correct output. Encoding might be an issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quotation mark into .csv (per field) AWK/SED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157850/quotation-mark-into-csv-per-field-awk-sed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk can do all this in one command:

```
awk -F"," 'NR>1{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if (!($i ~ /^"/)) printf("\"%s\"",$i); 
           else printf("%s",$i); if (i<NF) printf(","); else print "";}}' latest.csv
```

**EDIT:**

Try this awk: (modified from JS's suggested command)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{gsub(/\"/,"");gsub(/[^,\r]+/,"\"&\"")}1'
```

OR

```
awk -F"[,\r]" 'NR==1{print} NR>1{for(i=1; i<NF; i++) {if (!($i ~ /^"/)) 
               printf("\"%s\"",$i); else printf("%s",$i); if (i<NF-1) printf(",");
               else print "";}}'
```

Comment: same problem, random enters between end of the line

Comment: Can you show me output of `>head -n2 latest.csv|od -c` command

Comment: 0000000   s   k   u   ,   i   t   e   m   ,   p   r   i   c   e   ,   q
0000020   t   y  \r  \n   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   8   3
0000040   5   ,   W   a   l   n   u   t       H   a   l   f   ,   2   .
0000060   7   9   ,   -   2   4  \r  \n
0000070

Comment: Any way to remove those \r?

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{gsub(/\"/,"");gsub(/[^,]+/,"\"&\"")}1' input
```

Comment: Same output like on the above, maybe there's something wrong in encoding?

result of input is: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

Comment: @AdamLesniak Looks like your file was created on windows. If you don't have `dos2unix` utility then run this `sed -i "s/\r$//g" input.csv`

Comment: Got installed dos2unix, not working when I put on dos2unix input.csv, still same output ;/ same with sed

Comment: @AdamLesniak Technically the best answer should go to [anubhava](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17176575/970195). He was the one solved your problem. :)

Comment: @JS웃: Thanks and much appreciated. Your awk command was much more concise that my original awk solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

Solution using sed:

```
sed -e 's/"//g; s/,/","/g; s/^/"/; s/$/"/'
```

Long-piped-commented version:

```
sed -e 's/"//g' | # removes all quotations
sed -e 's/,/","/g' | # changes all colons to ","
sed -e 's/^/"/; s/$/"/' # puts quotations in the start and end of each line
```